# How does Find My Mac work exactly?

Tags: icloud, filevault, find-my-mac

My Macbook Pro 13 (2015) was recently stolen. I activated FMM about an hour after the event and two hours later received an update that the machine was erased. Questions:

1) What does this mean exactly? Is this message triggered when the wipe is initiated or after the wipe is completed. Can I reliably infer that the HDD was wiped? What's to prevent the baddie from simply turning off the machine when the wipe is initiated? I'm just trying to understand the possible outcomes here, especially with the data on the drive.

2) The HDD was encrypted with filevault 2. Does this provide effective protection from anyone getting at the data?

3) Is the machine bricked (like an iOS device would be) or can it still be resold as a working computer?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you clicked on the option to "Erase your Mac" when you activated FMM.  If you got a message that the machine was erased, then the drive was erased.

As for the HDD, filevault does offer good protection against the most common of thieves, but nothing is perfect.  Chances are they can't crack the encryption.  However, if you wiped the drive, this is moot.

Is the machine "bricked?"  I don't know.  Did you lock it with a PIN code?  If you didn't, it can still work.  However, if you locked it down with a PIN, you have effectively bricked it.

Now...did you file a police report?

Comment: Yes, I did click the option to "Erase your Mac" - which is, I am assuming, why a couple of hours later I got the message that it was erased. I did lock it with a pin so good to know its useless. Police report was filed since they got a few other goodies such as a passport and checkbook. Fun times.

Comment: Were you able to give them a location as to where the Mac was last located?  I have been where you are and it's no picnic.  I wish you the best with getting things squared away.

Comment: Yeah, I gave them the exact location where my car was burglarized. I didn't wait around for FMM to tell me where the crooks were with the Macbook - I wanted to render the computer useless so I decided to focus on getting it shut down. Thanks for the info and encouragement - e